# Отловить цифры перед заданным текстом в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Для динамической смены курса валюты на страницы пытаюсь отловить все цифры перед текстом 'рубль':

```
var curnums = $('body').text().match('^\D*(\d+) рублей.*$');
```

но в ответ тишина. Честно говоря, не совсем силен в регулярке.

Ну и в довесок - каким образом можно процесс отлавливания загнать в цикл, чтобы менять значение на нужное при нахождении подстроки?

Comment: вы напишите выходные данные, и то что хотите на выходе. и про цикл не ясно.

Comment: Вам нужно привести html-код блока, с которым вы работаете. И не совсем понятно, для чего вам нужно получить текущее значение

Comment: Входными данными является любой текст, в котором могут содержаться подстроки типа 1000 рублей, 12 382 рубля и т.д. На выходе - этот же текст, но 1000 рублей и 12 382 рубля становятся 16 USD и 206 USD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JavaScriptʼе `'^\D*(\d+) рублей.*$'` — это строка, а не регулярное выражение. Регулярные выражения заключаются в символы `/.../`. `'...'` — это строка, а не регулярное выражение, то есть в Вашем коде производится поиск строки `'^\D*(\d+) рублей.*$'`.

Дальше. Ваше регулярное выражение начинается с символа начала строки (`^`) и заканчивается символом конца строки (`$`). То есть сравнивается обязательно вся строка. Если Вы не проверяете всю строку на корректность, а ищите что-то внутри строки, не используйте `^` и `$`, они лишние.

Плюс уберите «что угодно» (`.*`) в конце, ведь в таком случае регулярное выражение захватит всё, что осталось, до конца — включая следующие числовые даты, а нам это не нужно.

Получаем такое регулярное выражение: `/(\d+) рублей/`

В принципе, после цифры может быть не только пробел, а и, например, табуляция. Так что лучше заменить  на `\s`. Причём пробельных символов может быть несколько, так что лучше поставить `+` (`\s+`).

Возможно, имеет смысл не только «рублей», но и «рубля», и «рубль», и «руб.», так что лучше сделать так: `/(\d+)\s+руб(лей|ля|ль|\.)/`

Правда, это не включает копейки. Предположим, что копейки идут сразу после рублей (вообще-то это не обязательно верно — смотрите свои входные данные, но предположим). Также предположим, что копейки без рублей не встречаются:

`/(\d+)\s+руб(лей|ля|ль|\.)(\s*(\d+)\s+коп(еек|йки|йка|\.))?/`

Я обвёл копейки в скобки и поставил `?` после скобок, чтобы указать, что что копейки указывать не обязательно.

Чтобы заменить все значения, можно использовать функцию `replace`, передав ей функцию — примерно вот так:

```
исходнаяСторока.replace(/регулярка/g, function (match, скобки1, скобки2, скобки3, ...) {
  return 'чем заменить';
});
```

`g` после регулярного выражения обозначает, что заменить нужно не только первое вхождение, а все вхождения.

Для примера, вот функция, которая переводит рубли в доллары:

```
function rublesToDollars(str, course) {
  return str.replace(
    /(\d+)\s+руб(лей|ля|ль|\.)(\s*(\d+)\s+коп(еек|йки|йка|\.))?/g,
    function (match, rubles, rub_ending, copecks_match, copecks, copecks_ending) {
      var rubles = parseInt(rubles);
      if (copecks) {
        rubles += parseInt(copecks) / 100;
      }
      var dollars = rubles / course;
      return dollars.toFixed(2) + '$';
    });
}
```

Вот пример использования:

```
rublesToDollars("Инна заказала пиццу Tut.by " +
    "за 8 рублей 90 копеек, а я — салат за 5 рублей " +
    "50 копеек", 1.9031)
```

Результат:

```
"Инна заказала пиццу Tut.by за 4.68$, а я — салат за 2.89$"
```

Дальше нужно применить это ко всему тексту. `$("body").text()` точно не подходит, так как это преобразование с потерей данных: вы теряете все теги внутри `<body>`, вы по сути делаете из HTMLʼа неформатированный текст.

Функция выше может работать только с текстом, но не с тегами. Если вы знаете, что текст с суммами будет храниться только в определённых элементах (например, в описаниях товаров), то проще всего заменить текст только в этих элементах.

Если Вам нужно что-то более универсальное, то лучше воспользоваться готовыми плагинами для замены во всём коде. Например, https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText

Comment: Все предельно понятно. Очень крутое объяснение, спасибо. Вам нужно книги писать, если уже не начали=)